# Not able to configure JMS queue in WSO2 IoT server : missing documentation

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I am using the following setting in `JMS` queue receiver using the settings  given [here](https://wso2.com/library/articles/2013/03/configuring-wso2-esb-wso2-message-broker/)

```
 <property name="java.naming.factory.initial">org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory</property>
    <property name="java.naming.provider.url">repository/conf/jndi.properties</property>
    <property name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName">TopicConnectionFactory</property>
    <property name="transport.jms.UserName">admin</property>
```

I am getting the following error

```
Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Failed to create InitialContext using factory specified in hash table. [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: class org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory not found]
    at org.wso2.carbon.context.internal.CarbonContextDataHolder$CarbonInitialJNDIContextFactoryBuilder.createInitialContextFactory(CarbonContextDataHolder.java:491)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:681)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSConnectionFactory.<init>(JMSConnectionFactory.java:84)
```

Can someone please point me to right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been solved. Please find the answer on my [blog](https://medium.com/@smartsplash/setting-up-jms-queue-in-wso2-iot-server-f20991821366) post.

Answer (score 1):

The exception gives us a big hint on what is causing the issue.

```
Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: class org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory not found
```

It looks like it is missing a library.
The guide mentions copying over the andes-client jar which contains the PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory class.

> WSO2 ESB needs some libraries to communicate with WSO2 Message Broker. They are available in [MB_HOME]/client-lib folder. Following libraries should be
>   copied to [ESB_HOME]/repository/components/lib folder.
>
> andes-client-0.13.wso2v3
>
> geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.1.0.wso2v1